# Swift - Reuse the old instance of view when switch between Views and Passing data over views

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a simple app and here is how it works:

When the user clicks the button "Picking", it'll show a tableview. And when the user selects a row in the table view, it will show the first view and display the data on the label.
[image]

I have 2 problems:

1. Every time I click the button "Picking", a new instance of the table view controller gets created; but does not reuse the existing one. How can I make it reuse the old one?
2. I want to pass the selected data to the root view. I tried by creating a segue to show the root view when user selects a cell and then passing the data on `prepareForSegue` method. But, I faced the above problem of memory leak. How do I pass the data between screens without leaking memory?

Answer (score 0):

1. It sounds like you may be making a circular view hierarchy. When you tap on the cell in the table view, if you're pushing a new instance of the first VC, that is the wrong way to do it IMO.

   Instead, you should pass the data back to the first VC then dismiss the second VC. Then, when you tap on the "Picking" button again, it's a new instance of the table view but your previous instance has already been removed from memory.

   This allows for the smallest amount of memory to be used at any given time. When the table view controller isn't on the screen, it doesn't need to be in memory.
2. IMO, the best way to pass data up a navigation stack is to use a protocol and delegate. It's similar to how Objective-C protocols and delegates worked if you're familiar with that. Here is Apple's documentation on both. The delegate section is about 1/3 the way down the page.
   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Jay